# Conflict between `pushd .` and `cd -`

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command, pushd

I am a happy user of the `cd -` command to go to the previous directory. At the same time I like `pushd .` and `popd`.

However, when I want to remember the current working directory by means of `pushd .`, I lose the possibility to go to the previous directory by `cd -`. (As `pushd .` also performs `cd .`).

How can I use `pushd` to still be able to use `cd -`

By the way: GNU bash, version 4.1.7(1)

Comment: Why not use `pwd` to figure out where you are?

Comment: I don't understand your question? The point is that pushd breaks the behavior of `cd -` that I want (or expect). I know perfectly well in which directory I am, but I want to increase the speed with which I change directories :)

Comment: You waid "when I want to remember the current working directory by means of `pushd .`". If you want to remember the current working directory, thats what `pwd` is for.

Comment: @Patrick But this is information is lost when I change directories again.

Comment: Do you know `zsh`? It has really nice features like AUTO_PUSHD.

Comment: +1 Thank you for teaching me about cd -! For most of a decade, I've been doing $ cd $OLDPWD instead.

Comment: @bernhard Oh, I misunderstood what you were asking. You were wanting to know how to *store* the current working directory. I was interpreting it as you wanted to remember (as in you forgot) your current working directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
push() { 
    if [ "$1" = . ]; then
        old=$OLDPWD
        current=$PWD
        builtin pushd .
        cd "$old"
        cd "$current"
    else
        builtin pushd "$1"
    fi
}
```

If you name it `pushd`, then it will have precedence over the built-in as functions are evaluated before built-ins.

You need variables `old` and `current` as overwriting `OLDPWD` will make it lose its special meaning.

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Is there no such feature in the built-in pushd? As I would always prefer a standard solution. Thanks for this function however, maybe I will leave out the argument and it's checking at some point.

Comment: There is no such feature in the builtin. Your own function is the best solution because pushd and popd both call `cd` modifying $OLDPWD, hence the source of your problem. I would name the function saved and use it in the context you like too, that of saving cwd.

Comment: You might also want to unset `old` and `current` after you're done with them.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more concise version of [Wojtek's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32268/11750):

```
pushd () {
        if [ "$1" = . ]; then
                cd -
                builtin pushd -
        else    
                builtin pushd "$1"
        fi      
}
```

By naming the function `pushd`, you can use `pushd` as normal, you don't need to remember to use the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's answer is excellent. I've written up some details about what's going on, in case people are looking for a better understanding of why their script is necessary to solve the problem.

The reason that `pushd .` breaks the behavior of `cd -` will be apparent if we dig into the workings of cd and the directory stack. Let's push a few directories onto the stack:

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3
$ pushd dir1
~/dir1 ~
$ pushd../dir2
~/dir2 ~/dir1 ~
$ pushd../dir3
~/dir3 ~/dir2 ~/dir1 ~
$ dirs -v
0       ~/dir3
1       ~/dir2
2       ~/dir1
3       ~
```

Now we can try `cd -` to jump back a directory:

```
$ cd -
/home/username/dir2
$ dirs -v
0       ~/dir2
1       ~/dir2
2       ~/dir1
3       ~
```

We can see that `cd -` jumped us back to the previous directory, replacing stack ~0 with the directory we jumped into. We can jump back with `cd -` again:

```
$ cd -
/home/username/dir3
$ dirs -v
0       ~/dir3
1       ~/dir2
2       ~/dir1
3       ~
```

Notice that we jumped back to our previous directory, even though the previous directory wasn't actually listed in the directory stack. This is because `cd` uses the environment variable `$OLDPWD` to keep track of the previous directory:

```
$ echo $OLDPWD
/home/username/dir2
```

If we do `pushd .` we will push an extra copy of the current directory onto the stack:

```
$ pushd . 
~/dir3 ~/dir3 ~/dir2 ~/dir1 ~
$ dirs -v
0       ~/dir3
1       ~/dir3
2       ~/dir2
3       ~/dir1
4       ~
```

In addition to making an extra copy of the current directory in the stack, `pushd .` has updated `$OLDPWD`:

```
$echo $OLDPWD
/home/username/dir3
```

So `cd -` has lost its useful history, and will now just move you to the current directory - accomplishing nothing.